# How do I use two separate Spring yaml config files at the same time?

Tags: java, spring

I have application.yml, and I have a second file. It can be named anything, but I need to load from both of them. They won't have overlap, so overwriting is not a concern. Unfortunately, I cannot use profiles to separate the data and need two files.

For the file structure, I have:

```
src
 main
  resources
   application.yml
   layer2
    secondFile.yml
```

I have tried:

1. Adding spring.config.additional-location to my application.yml. This never seems to load the second file. I have tried with both `classpath` and `file`, but I could be doing it wrong.
2. In the Application.java, changing main to use `System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "{file and classpath attempts}")`, as well as creating a new set of properties and passing them in to the SpringApplication before running it.

Is there something I am missing? I could be formatting the classpath or file selection wrong, but I am not sure how to go about testing that.

For the first style of attempt, application.yml is just:

```
spring:
  config:
    additional-location: "optional:classpath:/layer2/secondFile.yml"
```

Comment: Why can't you use profiles?

Comment: @Andreas I am trying to simplify by removing some common configs from multiple modules. So the end goal I am hoping for is having something like a common config, with each module having an application.yml with the project specific information.

Comment: So why couldn't each module also be a profile? Allowing you to put module-specific configuration into the profile-specific configuration files? A profile is (means) what you decide it is.